# Locking use of webpage while action is called

Tags: html, ajax

I have a series of `html` webpages that have some user interactivity for example:

[image: Adding groups example]

The buttons link to `php` files that perform the tasks of adding/deleting records from an `SQL` database.

The problem I face is that with a slow connection the user may feel that the button has not been clicked and therefore click it again causing the `php` to be called again.

I would like to have a type of progress bar appear on the screen when the button is clicked therefore locking out the website from further use until the `php` routine has completed and the page is refreshed.

I am assuming that it will be an `Ajax` type call.

Answer (score 1):

Using a progress bar for adding records is pretty useless as they're making your webpage slower because the user has to load a bunch of javascript and the progress bar styling. You better disable the buttons as soon as they're clicked and change the cursor to `load` so the user sees that something is going on.

jQuery:

```
$( ".submit-button" ).click(function() {
    $(".submit-button").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

CSS:

```
.submit-button:active {
    cursor:load;
}
```

In this example, `.submit-button` your submit button `class`.